# WinRT GridView But No GridViewColumn

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I do not have Windows 8 and Metro installed.  My question is based on the documentation.

It appears DataGrid is gone but ListView and GridView remain.  GridViewColumn is gone.  I get the tile nature of Metro.   My question is can GridView be configured for a row column presentation?

I have an app that for the most part would present great under Metro and would benefit from rights contracts.   But there is one page were I need old school GridViewColumn like presentation.   Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got your question. You want elements added to a ListView/GridView are displayed in a row?
I use for the following code to display items in a horizontal orientation:

```
<GridView>
 <GridView.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
   <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
 </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```

Comment: My question is can you get headers and data to line up cleanly in column.  With the Source as rows.

Comment: Well I think there is currently no metro UI control that provide this functionality (maybe it's a beta limitation?). Of course you can build a user control with this functionality.

Comment: Maybe you could build that user control but I don't know how.

Comment: If you need some inspiration look how the `DataGrid` is build, which is included in the `Silverlight 5 Toolkit`, it's OpenSource. http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/78435 . I would suggest that you can reuse a lot of code.