# c# GridViewColumns missing assembly reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5, assembly-references

I am trying to use 'System.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn' within Visual Studio 2013, .net 4.5, but I am receiving this error :

> The type 'GridViewColumn' was not found. Verify that you are not
>   missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have
>   been built.

Looking within my Reference Manager, I have this message under the Assemblies tab :

> All of the Framework assemblies are already referenced. Please use the
>   Object Browser to explore the references in the Framework.

When I browse through I cannot find 'PresentationFramework.dll'.
Here is the MSDN for the class : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
```

I have tried to add `using System.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn` but am receiving this error:

> The type or namespace name `Controls` does not exist in the namespace
>   `System.Windows` (are you missing an assembly reference?)

EDIT:

For WhyCry, when I search as you suggested I still don't get any results.
[image]
Perhaps I need to use a different GridView? Maybe `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls`?

Comment: Try to add just: using System.Windows.Controls 
Then go to your references, right click and add reference, in assemblies, search for System.Windows.Controls and add it that way.

Comment: What about if you rebuild the solution or exit and reopen VS? I know those aren't the greatest solutions, but sometimes I find  things like that just seem to happen.

Comment: Is your project a WPF project?

Comment: I searched for System.Windows.Controls within the Reference Manager as you suggested, but it said 'No items found.'

Comment: I'm typing the answer, found a way to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a WPF project, I do know it is a Windows Store App and I am using XAML in the designer. How can I check if it is WPF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're creating Windows store apps, which is based on [WinRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx), while  this GridViewColumn control is one of the WPF controls.

WPF and WinRT are mutually exclusive, you can not use WPF control in Windows Store apps.  Please read this: [Windows 8 Store Applications Vs. WPF Applications](http://jesseliberty.com/2013/03/29/windows-8-store-applications-vs-wpf-applications/)

Answer (score 2):

Okay. So in your Solution Explorer, Right click **References**, and **Add Reference**. Then make sure Framework is highlighted in the top left corner of the Dialog. Search for PresentationFramework in the top right search bar. Add PresentationFramework.

After this is done, do:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
```

You can then access all of the `GridViewColumn` variables, objects, to your hearts desire.

```
System.Windows.Controls.Gridview
```

References:
[GridViewColumn MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.celltemplate(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Namespace:  System.Windows.Controls

Assembly:  PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)

**MIGHT NEED TO SCROLL IN ON IMAGE**
[image: PresentationFramework Screenshot]

Comment: I'm still not finding that, I added a screenshot to my question. Thank you for the help!

Comment: What kind of project do you have? Like when you hit New Project, what did you select? @Brian

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. It turns out the issue was my app is a WinRT instead of a WPF. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183294/winrt-gridview-but-no-gridviewcolumn Perhaps this might offer help? @Brian